# Use rsync to clone one server to another?

Tags: debian, rsync, webserver, clone

I have two Debian 9 servers, server A and Server B.

Server A is a LAMP stack server.

Server A is slow. Server B is fast.

I want to clone server A to server B without shutting down server A.

How do I do that?

I *think* I can do something like this:

1. Install Debian 9 on server B as a base installation
2. use rsync to copy over all of `/home/` from A to B, then copy over /etc/passwd, /etc/groups, and /etc/shadow
3. Dump the packages that are installed on A, create a script to install those on B.
4. Dump the MySQL databases from A, copy to B, and import
5. Copy over the contents of /etc/ with rsync.

Or... could I just rsync the ENTIRE server from B to A?

Answer (score 3):

#### Please read over each link carefully before attempting any commands.

I have used this [rsync example](https://serverfault.com/a/25398/458184) by user ericslaw to successfully clone my working Linux install to a different drive.

You can mount a remote or local target file system to `/mnt` of your source file system. As root(sudo) run the following:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

`/dev/sdb1` is your second server disk. It can be remote or local, whatever works best for you.

```
rsync -gloptruncv \
      --exclude={/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found} \ 
      / /mnt
```

This will be a dry run. If there are no errors then you should be good to go to exclude the `n` option. After which you need to follow the advice in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/709176/how-to-best-clone-a-running-system-to-a-new-harddisk-using-rsync). After your back up has completed ( You can even use their options instead depending on your circumstances) Then reset `/mnt/etc/fstab` for the boot and swap partitions. I highly recommend these entries are based on the `UUID` of the block devices. `blkid` will tell the information you need. After `fstab` is fixed you need to run `grub-install /dev/[serverB disk]` to be able to boot. Alternatively you can `chroot` into the backup and install grub that way.

```
 chroot /mnt
 grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb1
 update-grub
```

Lastly you may need to recreate the missing folders of your backup (`/dev/, /proc/, /sys/, /tmp/, /run/, /mnt/, /media/, and /lost+found`).

This can also be done in reverse. Have Server B mount Server A's disk and then sync non system files between the two. This is easiest if Server A and B are running the same version of the same distro.

Comment: I think, you should exclude some more directories and files: `/etc/fstab,/etc/mtab,/var/tmp/`

Comment: What about the options `rsync -aAX` aren't those A and X needed too for an exact copy?